# value of enum field in dataclass converts to string after instantiation in python

Tags: python, django, dictionary, enums, python-dataclasses

I have an enum class.
and a dataclass containing a field with that enum class type.
When i try to create an instance with an unpacked dictionary value of that enum field converts to string.

Imagine this is my enum class

```
class Statuses(Enum):
    SEND = 1
    ACK = 2
    NACK = 3
```

and this is my dataclass containing that enum

```
@dataclass
class Message:
    status: Statuses
```

when i try to make an instance by unpacking a dictionary like this:

```
some_dict = {"status":"1"}
instance = Message(**some_dict)
```

by printing instance i get this:

```
Message(status='1')
```

while i expected like this :

```
Message(status=Statuses.SEND)
```

Comment: *why* did you expect that? That is never how this would work, this has nothing to do with enums. Try it with jsut `int` and `str` and pass only strings. Or lists, or whatever type. Python is a dynamically typed language, and dataclasses don't implement any validation for you

Comment: " value of that enum field converts to string." No, *nothing is converted*. Your dictionary *has a string*. So that is why a string is passed.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes i was wrong, thanks a lot.

Comment: Consider using a libary like [pydantic](https://docs.pydantic.dev/) if you want automatic type conversion/validation. They even have a drop-in replacement for the standard library `dataclasses`: [pydantic dataclasses](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/dataclasses/)